# Python Anaconda: how to test if updated libraries are compatible with my existing code?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using a Python 2.7 Anaconda installation on a Windows 7 machine for data analysis and scientific computing.

When new libraries are released (e.g. a new version of pandas, patsy, etc), how would you recommend I test the compatibility of the new version with my existing code? Is it possible to have two Anaconda installations on the same machine? Would you recommend some kind of virtual environment? Is there an easy way to roll back to previous versions of a library with Anaconda?

I ask because have spent the best part of the last week trying to figure out why my previous code no longer works with the new versions of pandas and patsy. No need to comment how mad I am because of this...

Incidentally, this also goes to show that Python is a potentially interesting language for data analysis and scientific computing, but only potentially. The main libraries are too unstable and immature. Pandas was released about 3 1/2 years ago and we're still very far from a v 1.0, so I'm not hopeful that things will get better with time. Imagine if every new release of Matlab required a major rewrite of all your code: Mathworks would have gone out of business long ago!

Comment: Look at the changelogs for the individual packages. They will list the breaking changes, if any.

Comment: Sorry, I guess the question wasn't clear. The question was more about how best to handle these cases. Can I have two separate Anaconda distributions on the same machine? A 'stable' one and one where I test if the new libraries are compatible with my existing code? Or is there a quick way to rollback to a previous version of a library in Anaconda?

Answer (score 4):

You could install the specific versions of all the dependencies in a separate virtual environment and test you module there. This can be achieved with the following work-flow,

```
$ conda create --yes -n new_env pip numpy=1.9 pandas=0.16 python=2 # specify the required versions
$ activate new_env
$ # install and test your module
$ deactivate
```

You can have as many virtual environment as you want on a machine.

I can understand the frustration when things break on an update, but IMHO the core scientific modules in python (numpy, scipy, and pandas getting there) are pretty stable and mature. Stability is not about having a version 1.0. True, there can be some backward incompatible changes, because it's the price to pay to have improvements and keep a manageable code base, but overall things are rather reasonable.

It's more about the deployment/testing strategy that shouldn't be tied to an install on a given machine. If you use version control with continuous integration (CI) and deploying in a virtual environment, it should be pretty easy to revert to the previous setup if something breaks on an update.

Comment: I beg to differ. Pandas 0.14 can not output nulls to sql with the to_sql method. So I upgraded to pandas 0.16, which outputs nulls to sql, but is so slow it's effectively unusable (6 minutes to transfer an 11 MB table! And then people talk about Python and big data? Don't make me laugh...). Pandas 0.16 has also changed how csv files are read into dataframes, so I had to rewrite all my data cleansing routines. A column was read as a string in 0.14 and as a date in 0.16.

Comment: A way of assigning values to a dataframe which was perfectly fine in 0.14 now returns a warning in 0.16, and a routine implementing this way of populating a dataframe, which was fine in 0.14, now takes 20 times more time in 0.16. Oh, patsy changed to, and I had to rewrite part of my code for patsy, too.

Comment: Maybe I was extremely unlucky. All I know is, after spending a week trying to fix all these issues, I am very, very furious and have developed a contempt for all things Python which I didn't imagine would have ever been possible. How can I know that the next upgrade of anothe rlibrary won't totally mess up my code again? I will be looking into Matlab as an alternative because these backward incompatible changes are inconceivable in a commercial environment like Matlab. Also, Matlab's documentation is second to none - so much better than Python's

Comment: Oh, one more thing. Somewhere between pandas 0.14 and 0.16 categorical dtypes were introduced to dataframes. Great! However, I had a lot of code which uses pandas.cut to discretise numeric variables into ranges, and then convert nas into the text missing. Now that gives an error, because I must first add 'missing' to the list of possible categories, and only then can I assign the value 'missing' to items of the series. So time-consuming and infuriating to change all my code because of this!

Comment: OK, I can see the reason for your frustration. However, as you noticed  `pandas` is only 3.5 years old (compare that to 12+  years for `numpy`) and is indeed going through a very fast development process, which unfortunately seems introduce a number of backward incompatible changes.  Few comments however (a) you don't have to use the last version of `pandas` (b) `pandas` is great, but I personally wouldn't  write a module that use pandas and expect it to work flawlessly as is 2 years from now with a new release: use `numpy`, `scipy` if you need stability (or even C/Fortran wrapped modules).

Comment: Also `pandas` != scientific python (i.e. scipy/numpy) != Python. If an updated routine is slow in `pandas` submit an issue on github, it has nothing to do with Python....

Comment: There's no need to install Miniconda if you already have Anaconda. Just use conda (which already comes with Anaconda) to create a new environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would clone your environment with conda

```
# Replace update-tests with whatever you want to call the environment
# Replace root with the environment name if you use a non-root environment
conda create -n update-tests --clone root
```

Then update the packages in that environment

```
conda install -n update-tests pandas=0.16 ...
```

Then activate that environment to test it

```
# On non-Windows this would be 'source activate update-tests'
activate update-tests
```

You can deactivate after with

```
# Would be 'source deactivate' on non-Windows
deactivate
```