# python pandas 0.16: SettingWithCopyWarning incorrectly reported

Tags: python, pandas

As per my other question:
[Python Anaconda: how to test if updated libraries are compatible with my existing code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850542/python-anaconda-how-to-test-if-updated-libraries-are-compatible-with-my-existin)

I curse the day I was forced to upgrade to pandas 0.16.
One of the things I don't understand is why I get a chained assignment warning when I do something as banal as adding a new field to an existing dataframe and initialising it with 1:

```
mydataframe['x']=1
```

causes the following warning:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   mydataframe['x']=1

I understand there can be problems when assigning values to a copy of a dataframe, but here I am just adding a new field to a dataframe! How am I supposed to change my code (which worked perfectly in previous versions of pandas)?

Comment: Unless you provide a fully self-contained example, we can't tell whether it's a bug or if it's that you've been ignoring the docs for a long time and it's only now it's been revealed.

Comment: I did provide the example. I load a dataframe and then the single line of code I copied above: mydataframe['x']=1 is the one which triggers the warning

Comment: Sorry but if `mydataframe`really is your original df and not a copy or a slice/view then this warning won't appear, also is SO *really* the right place to moan about this? Shouldn't you post something on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) preferably with an MVCE?

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous: you may have missed the words "fully self-contained".

Comment: OK, I just deleted the minor rant in the last paragraph in accordance with the posting procedures here.  @Pythonistaanonymous -- I am sympathetic to your question here as I sometimes get that message too, and can't tell why.  But it's impossible to do anything unless you can help other people to reproduce the error message.  So we need to see the code you used prior to getting the message, or just any code that causes that initialization line to generate the message.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at an answer, or at least an attempt to reproduce the message.  (Note that you may only get this message once and might need to start a new shell or do `%reset` in ipython to get this message.)

```
In [1]: %reset

Once deleted, variables cannot be recovered. Proceed (y/[n])? y

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: pd.__version__
Out[3]: '0.16.0'
```

Here are 3 variations of setting a new column to '1'.  The first two do not generate the warning, but the third one does.  (Second one thanks to @Jeff's suggestion)

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[77,88,99] })
   ...: df['z'] = 1

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[77,88,99] })
   ...: df = df[1:]
   ...: df['z'] = 1

In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[77,88,99] })
   ...: df2 = df[1:]
   ...: df2['z'] = 1

-c:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable
/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Perhaps others can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the error message here is relating to `df2` being a copy of a slice of `df`.  However, that's not really an issue as the resulting `df` and `df2` are what I would have expected:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   x   y
0  1  77
1  2  88
2  3  99

In [8]: df2
Out[8]: 
   x   y  z
1  2  88  1
2  3  99  1
```

I know this is going to be terrible to say, but when I get that message I just check to see whether the command did what I wanted or not and don't overly think about the warning.  But whether you get a warning message or not, checking that a command did what you expected is really something you need to do all the time in pandas (or matlab, or R, or SAS, or Stata, ... )

Comment: note that if in the 2nd part of the example, if you do: ``df = df[1:]; df['z'] = 1``. you will NOT get a warning (maybe show this as well). The warning happens because of setting a column on something which is sliced, THEN set, IOW, its de-factor the same as ``df[1:]['z'] = 1`` and expecting it to work.

Comment: @Jeff  Thanks, I added your suggestion to the code.  Please write up a more complete answer if you are so inclined.  I don't understand this fully and am just trying to help to frame the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will not generate the warning:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[77,88,99] })
df2 = df[1:].copy()
df2['z'] = 1
```